# Validate dynamic txt file with unicode tags using javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

I need to validate a text file with a dynamic content, but it's generated with unicode tags for each line. I use other file as a baseline to compare the files and check if the file created is equal to the expected.

i split both files with \n and compare each line from the files, but i have some issues with encondig/unicode characters.

Tried using this regex https://regex101.com/r/nXTkrP/1, but it fails when comparing both files, as unicode seems to change when i copy the content from expected to baseline to be compared.

Basic logic would be:

```
var txtFile = readFileText(file).split("\n");
var baselines = readFileText(baseline).split("\n");

if (file.indexOf(baseline) = -1){
    var equals = true;
}
```

Is there any way to "force" encondig of both files to compare, or any other suggestion on using regex to ensure the layout is the same and the content is the same?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your file(s) and what you mean by validating it? What conditions does your file need to satisfy in order to be validated?